Exporting QGraphicsScene with items and importing them back into the application
Is there a way to export my QGraphicsScene with all the items and import it without customizing it?
I am working on a Qt C++ application with a QGraphicsScene, where the user inserts items and connects them.
I want to add functionality for the user to export their diagram and import it again and continue working on it, is there an easy way to do so or do I need to build it myself.

No, there is not.

This question is similar to: Save/Load items from a QGraphicsScene. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I know this doesn't answer your "Yes/No" question, but it does answer "How". As already mentioned, this feature does not exist, so yes you have to build it yourself. There's also this blog in case it helps: Save QGraphicsScene to XML File By Using QXmlStreamWriter

To further clarify, the reason for which a save/restore feature isn't available is that, by its nature, QGraphicsItem is intended for extreme extensibility; Qt only provides a few "primitive" items that are simple enough to allow some form of serialization, many others cannot do that (how do you serialize a QGraphicsProxyWidget, since widgets cannot be serialized?): implementing a save/restore for shapes only would be quite pointless, and wouldn't work for more complex items or even custom QGraphicsItem subclasses (which are quite common), forcing the dev to reimplement it on their own anyway.
